# Start a process with high priority and redirect its stdout on Windows

Tags: windows, cmd.exe

How can I start a process with high priority and still redirect its standard output (stdout) to a file at same time?

This does not work:

```
start /HIGH my_little_proggy.exe > output.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

The /B flag is what you are looking for. The following works (at least on Windows 10):

```
start /HIGH /B my_little_proggy.exe > output.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

[ EDIT #2 - major correction ] As pointed by @TarnayKálmán (the OP) in a comment, the shell does not start child processes at its own priority level, but rather at the default normal priority. At the API level, cmd appears to be calling [CreateProcess](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425.aspx)  without setting any `PRIORITY_CLASS` in `dwCreationFlags` (as opposed to passing its own `GetPriority()`) which causes the child process to run at default `NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS`.

As a consequence, commands like `start /HIGH call my_little_proggy.exe ^> output.txt` will start a secondary cmd.exe shell at *high* priority, which in turn will handle the redirection and run `my_little_proggy.exe` - but run it at normal priority. Because of that, the following post does not answer the original question of redirecting the output when `start /HIGH`.

I edited out the `/HIGH` switch from my previous post, and left the rest below since the techniques do work for `start` in general, and someone may find this useful.

---

The way it's written, the `>` redirection applies to the `start` command itself, not the command that `start` actually runs (in your example, `my_little_proggy.exe`). This also explains why `start /B` works, since the child process shares the same console (assuming `my_little_proggy.exe` is a console app, too).

To redirect the output of the `start`'ed command, you need to (a) run the command via a secondary shell (either `cmd /c` or simply `call`), and (b) escape the `>` so that it's not interpreted as a special/redirection character by the `start` line, but rather is preserved and passed on to the child shell which runs `my_little_proggy.exe`. Either of the following should do that (note the `^>`).

```
start call my_little_proggy.exe ^> output.txt
start cmd /c my_little_proggy.exe ^> output.txt
```

---

[ EDIT #1 ] Added the `call` or `cmd /c` requirement in the paragraph above. Reason is that the `>` output redirection is handled by the command line interpreter, not by the target program itself, so in order for it to work the target `my_little_proggy.exe` must be launched by a command shell, as opposed to being run directly.

Comment: After a quick try, this does not appear to work. I tried `start /HIGH ping bix.hu ^> ping.txt`. The file is not even created, and ping.exe terminates immediately.

Comment: "Bad parameter >." - says ping(?)

Comment: `start /high cmd /c ping bix.hu ^>00` works fine here.

Comment: P.S. Edited the post to clarify the `call` or `cmd /c` requirement.

Comment: Yeah...That starts it and redirects the output, but only the new cmd.exe is running with high priority, and ping is not.

Comment: Confirmed and acknowledged, I made the necessary edits above. Hoped there would be a pure batch solution other than `start /b` (which has its own quirks unrelated to `/high`) but I'll concede that I don't see one at this point.